# Initial browser re-rendering when fetching data asynchronously

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to build a React app/site that uses "react-router", "redux" and server-side rendering and I don't quite understand how to deal with the initial rendering in the browser.

On the server side, I can take a JSON object, pass it to the state and then map state to props - all synchronously - and finally render the component using already initialized props.

```
const routes = <Router>
<Route path='/' component={ViewComposite} 
  onEnter={ ({params}) => { store.dispatch(setViewProps(props)); }} />
<Route path='/admin' component={AdminComposite} 
  onEnter={ ({params}) => { store.dispatch(setAdminProps(props)); }} />
</Router>;
```

However, when the browser comes into play, I need to fetch data via AJAX request - asynchronously:

```
window.onload = function() {
const store = createStore(viewPropsReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store} >
        <Router history={browserHistory} >
            <Route path="/" component={ViewComposite} 
 onEnter={ ({params}) => {store.dispatch(fetchViewData()); }} />
            <Route path='/admin' component={AdminComposite} 
 onEnter={ ({params}) => {store.dispatch(fetchAdminData()); }} />
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('viewMount')
);}
```

As a result, the rendering fails due to undefined props.
Is there a way to work around this - maybe postpone browser rendering until the data is fetched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the json payload to the server rendered html.

```
<script> 
    window.payload = <json>
 </script>
```

If your state is serializable, I guess you could just put the state there instead, and pass it as initialState when creating the store.

```
createStore(reducer, window.initialState);
```

Comment: Yeah. We also have a [server rendering recipe](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html) in the official docs describing exactly that. However, I still recommend that each reducer specifies its initial state because I believe server rendering is an optimization, and an app should be able to boot up on the client without it anyway.

Comment: So, basically two main options are: either request data manually and invoke ReactDOM.render after the data is already fetched, or append the serialized payload to window object and then use it.

Comment: In the first option i would start the app right away and show a loading indicator until all the data is in, but yeah, that's the main options.